# BC V22 W1 On-Prem - API v2.0 - Standard endpoints not found

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

First time integrating with Business Central.  It's an on-prem installation for which the implementation is in progress, was V16 initially but then upgraded to V22 W1 during the development cycle.  Development was done to create a general journal, integrate lines to it, and then post the journal.  On V16 we were able to query things like customers, currencies, journals, i.e. standard available endpoints as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/, however since upgrading to V22 these standard endpoints no longer seem to be available / accessible.

1. We can query companies or a specific company as below, and results are returned.

[image]

2. However, when trying to go down any further like querying the customers for a specific company as below, we're getting a 404 not found.

[image]

From what I've been able to find it doesn't seem like specific endpoints, e.g. company(guid)/currencies, can be enabled / disabled for the API, you can only turn the whole API off of on via configuration, and unless I'm missing something obvious the format of the URL is also correct.

Why would we be receiving 404's when calling standards endpoints like customers, currency, journals, etc. but companies are being returned as per the first screenshot?

Comment: Can you verify that the customers endpoint is listed in http://bcserver:7048/BC/api/v2.0/$metadata
output:
{
    "name": "customers",
    "kind": "EntitySet",
    "url": "customers"
}

Comment: I did check the $metadata and no it's not listed, why it's not being listed is what I'm not sure about though.  The endpoints mentioned were there on the V16 as we called them previously, and I can't find anything in the documentation which indicates that specific endpoints need to be published for the API V2l0, similar to how they need to be published for OData.

Answer (score 1):

Okey, so seems that the API v2.0 is an extension / app, which needs to be installed, the extension / app's name is "*Exclude_APIV2*".

Using the Business Central Administration Shell I:

1. Ran the `Get-NAVAppInfo -ServerInstance <ServerInstance>` command to get a list of all the extension / app's published to the instance to confirm that the extension exists on the environment, which it did.
2. Ran the `Install-NAVApp -ServerInstance <ServerInstance> -Name "_Exclude_APIV2_"` command to install the extension.
3. Calling the .../api/v2.0/$metadata endpoint now shows all the expected endpoints and doing calls like .../api/v2.0/companies(guidhere)/customers or journals returns the expected results instead of the 404 received previously.

Note that if the required extension is not listed in the results from step 1, the `Publish-NAVApp -ServerInstance <ServerInstanceName> -Path "<PathToExtensionFile>"` command needs to be run first to publish the extension / app to the specific instance.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).